# Entity Framework TPT Removing base type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have the following models in my application:

```
public interface IBaseEntityObject 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}


public abstract class BaseEntityObject : IBaseEntityObject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id {get; set;}
}


public class Folder : BaseEntityObject
{   
    [DataMember]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public virtual List<Letter> Letters {get; set;} 
}


public abstract class Letter : BaseEntityObject
{   
    [DataMember]
    public string Title {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public string Content {get; set;}

    public virtual Folder Folder {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public int FolderId {get; set;}

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime CreationDate {get; set;}
}

public class OutgoingLetter : Letter
{
    // .. OutgoingLetter properties
}

public class ReceviedLetter : Letter
{
    // .. ReceviedLetter properties
}


public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Folder> Folders {get; set;}

    public DbSet<Letter> Letters {get; set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Folder <-> Letters       
        modelBuilder.Entity<Letter>()
        .HasRequired(t => t.Folder)
        .WithMany(f => f.Letters)
        .HasForeignKey(t => t.FolderId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}
```

However, no matter what I try, removing a folder results in access key violation.

After that, I tried removing all the letters in the folder before deleting it (which I didn't like)
and it resulted in another exception - Null value for non-nullable member.

what is the correct and most efficient way for me to remove a Folder?

**Edit**:

The code I tried for removing folder:

```
public abstract class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    protected readonly DbContext Context;

    public EFRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public abstract List<T> Get();

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Add(item);
    }

    public virtual Remove(T item)
    {
        Context.Set<T>().Remove(item);
    }

    public void Update(T item)
    {
        Context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Context.Dispose();
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public T FindById(int id)
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().Find(id); 
    }
}

public FoldersRepository : EFRepository<Folder>
{
    public FoldersRepository(DbContext context) : base(context) {}

    public void override Remove(Folder folder)
    {
        var letters = folder.Letters;

        for (int index = 0 ; index < letters.Count; index++)
        {
            Context.Set<Letter>().Remove(letters[0]);
        }

        base.Remove(folder);
    }
}
```

Is there a solution to this problem?
Still couldn't find one

Comment: When you remove a "Folder", do you first remove every "Letter" associated with that "Folder"?

Comment: At first I tried without removing it (which would highly prefer if it's possible) After that, I tried removing all the letters in the folder before deleting it (which I didn't like) and it resulted in another exception - Null value for non-nullable member.

Comment: Please post the code you use for deleting and the exact exception you are getting

Comment: If each Letter row has a foreign key pointing to a Folder row, you will unable to delete the Folder row as long as there are still Letters pointing to it.

Comment: EF model looks right. WillCascadeOnDelete(true) should do the job. Can you pleas show code how you delete a Folder ?

Comment: Edited, added my remove

Comment: When you call to FolderRepository.Delete, are you sure the letters collection is already loaded? I mean are you sure for loop is processing your letters?

Comment: Thanks for code, but what is base.Delete(folder) ? EFRepository doesn't  have Delete method. Do you mean base.Remove(folder)?

Comment: Yeah, it's loaded..
and sorry, I meant remove, edited.
Is this the way to do such a thing?

Comment: I'm lost with the error you are getting, but I know usually you can't traverse a collection while you are removing items, as the collection changes in every remove. Please try adding a ToList(): letters = folder.Letters.ToList();

Comment: It fails on the save changes afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recomend to change EF model setting and set  .HasOptional(t => t.Folder). It's really strange EF behaviour. But there are differenc between situation when you load Folder related Letters and not. Here a link to article that explain this differenvce [Working with Cascade Delete](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-entity-framework/9781449317867/ch04s04.html).

Anyway .HasOptional(t => t.Folder) should resolve the problem. 
And you can not change

```
    public int FolderId {get; set;}
```

to

```
    public int? FolderId {get; set;}
```

**Edit:**

If HasOptional(t => t.Folder) is not aceptable, you have two options:

1. =============

Set WillCascadeOnDelete(**false**). Load all folder's letters, remove all Letters and Folder. For examle

```
    var folder = Context.Set<Folder>().Include(f => f.Letters).First(f => f.Id==id);

    foreach(var letter in folder.Letters)
        Context.Set<Letter>().Remove(letter);

    Context.Set<Folder>().Remove(folder);
    Context.SaveChanges();
```

2. =============

Set WillCascadeOnDelete(**true**). Don't load any letters for folder that should be removed. Remove folder. For example:

```
    var folder = new Folder(){ Id = id };
    Context.Set<Folder>().Attach(folder);
    Context.Set<Folder>().Remove(folder);
    Context.SaveChanges();
```

**Edit2:**
I create some tests using the same EF model classes (Code First). All works without errors. I use the latest EntityFramework 6.1.3 version.
Below is the source code for the test:

```
    public class Folder {
       [Key]
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public List<Letter> Letters { get; set; } 
    }

    public class Letter {
       [Key]
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string Content { get; set; }
       public virtual Folder Folder { get; set; }
       public int FolderId { get; set; }
       public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
   }

   public class OutgoingLetter : Letter {
       public string AddressTo { get; set; }
   }

   public class ReceviedLetter : Letter {
       public string AddressFrom { get; set; }
   }

   public class MyDbContext : DbContext {
       public virtual DbSet<Folder> Folders { get; set; }

       public virtual DbSet<Letter> Letters { get; set; }

       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

           // Folder <-> Letters       
           modelBuilder.Entity<Letter>()
           .HasRequired(t => t.Folder)
           .WithMany(f => f.Letters)
           .HasForeignKey(t => t.FolderId)
           .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
       }
   }
   // ...........................................

   // TODO: Insert three Folders and related Letters.
   // Delete Folders and Leterrs in a three different ways.
   // In all cases Letters deleted throught WillCascadeOnDelete constraint.
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        using (var dtCntx = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var folder1 = new Folder() { Name = "Folder1" };
            var letters1 = new List<Letter>() { 
                new OutgoingLetter{Title = "Folder1-Letter1", CreationDate=DateTime.Now, Folder=folder1 },
                new ReceviedLetter{Title = "Folder1-Letter2", CreationDate=DateTime.Now, Folder=folder1 }
            };

            var folder2 = new Folder() { Name = "Folder2" };
            var letters2 = new List<Letter>() { 
                new OutgoingLetter{Title = "Folder2-Letter1", CreationDate=DateTime.Now, Folder=folder2 },
                new ReceviedLetter{Title = "Folder2-Letter2", CreationDate=DateTime.Now, Folder=folder2 }
            };

            var folder3 = new Folder() { Name = "Folder3" };
            var letters3 = new List<Letter>() { 
                new OutgoingLetter{Title = "Folder3-Letter1", CreationDate=DateTime.Now, Folder=folder3 },
                new ReceviedLetter{Title = "Folder3-Letter2", CreationDate=DateTime.Now, Folder=folder3 }
            };

            dtCntx.Folders.Add(folder1);
            dtCntx.Letters.AddRange(letters1);

            dtCntx.Folders.Add(folder2);
            dtCntx.Letters.AddRange(letters2);

            dtCntx.Folders.Add(folder3);
            dtCntx.Letters.AddRange(letters3);

            dtCntx.SaveChanges();
        }

        int id = 0;
        using (var dtCntx = new MyDbContext())
            id = dtCntx.Folders.First().Id;

        // Remove [Folder] and related [Letters] without loading [Folder] from DB
        using (var dtCntx = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var folder = new Folder { Id = id };
            dtCntx.Folders.Attach(folder);
            dtCntx.Folders.Remove(folder);
            dtCntx.SaveChanges();
        }
        // Load [Folder] from DB and delete it
        using (var dtCntx = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var folder = dtCntx.Folders.FirstOrDefault();
            dtCntx.Folders.Remove(folder);
            dtCntx.SaveChanges();
        }
        // Load [Folder] and all related [Letters]. Delete [Folder] and [Letters]
        using (var dtCntx = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var folder = dtCntx.Folders.Include(f => f.Letters).FirstOrDefault();
            dtCntx.Folders.Remove(folder);
            dtCntx.SaveChanges();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Successfully !!!");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

**Edit3:**
I change Folder model class.

```
     public class Folder
     {
       [Key]
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<Letter> Letters { get; set; }

       public override bool Equals(object obj)
       {
          var folder = obj as Folder;
          return folder.Id == this.Id && folder.Name == this.Name &&
            folder.Letters.SequenceEqual(this.Letters);
       }
       public override int GetHashCode()
       {
          return String.Concat(GetHashParts()).GetHashCode();
       }

       private IEnumerable<string> GetHashParts()
       {
          yield return Id.ToString();
          yield return Name;
          foreach (var letter in Letters) {
              yield return "_";
              yield return letter.Id.ToString();
          }
       }
       public static bool operator ==(Folder x, Folder y)
       {
           return x.Equals(y);
       }

       public static bool operator !=(Folder x, Folder y)
       {
          return !x.Equals(y);
       }
   }
```

I override Equals, == opeartor and GetHashCode. All old tests completed successfully again. But none of the new function has not been called. I know that behavior of EF have changed in latest versions. It's possible that in EF 5.* was different bihavior. I use lates EF 6.1.3. I change the test a bit and add a code to cause Equals function call. But code work without errors again.

```
     using (var dtCntx = new MyDbContext())
     {
            var folder = dtCntx.Folders.Include(f => f.Letters).FirstOrDefault();

            var folder2 = dtCntx.Folders.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == folder.Id);
            if (folder == folder2) Console.WriteLine("Equals"); // Call Folder.Equals

            dtCntx.Folders.Remove(folder);
            dtCntx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: .HasOptional will allow adding letters without FolderId won't it? I prefer not to allow it

Comment: Second option gives me access key violation

Comment: Strange ... I create exactly the same EF model classes and do tests (Except, I am not use Repository pattern). All tests were successfully passed. I will update answer to show tests code.

Comment: I think that the reason for this is that you didn't put virtual key word before the Letters List in Folder model, therefore lazy loading is not enabled. Can you try adding virtual and run it again? Thanks!

Comment: OK. I change `public List<Letter> Letters { get; set; }` to `public virtual List<Letter> Letters { get; set; }` in Folder class and do test again. All tests pass successfully. After that I change List to ICollection (`public virtual ICollection<Letter> Letters { get; set; }`) and again all tests completed successfully. I guess the problem somewhere else ...

Comment: First of all thank you so much..can you try this last thing:
In folder model override the Equals method and compare Ids, Names and Letters.

Comment: Not at all. EF Cascade Delete is an ineresting subject. I update answer. In my case Folder.Equals doesn't crash. But I guess It can cause an exception in some other situations. Stack trace can help.